# Is there a way to communicate between 2 Elasticsearch containers on the same host?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I deploy 2 container of Elasticsearch by the next commands:

```
docker run --network host  -p 9201:9200 -p 9301:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node"  docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.1 
docker run --network host  -p 9202:9200 -p 9302:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node"  docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.1
```

when I try to run the next command from one of the containers

```
curl localhost:${PORT_OF_THER_OTHER_CONTAINER}
```

I get the next error

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:PORT_OF_THER_OTHER_CONTAINER; Connection refused
```

Comment: Could you give the value of PORT_OF_THER_OTHER_CONTAINER ?

Comment: Which one failled?

Comment: Ok, it's normal behaviour because when you are into the container, the localhost is just this container, so the other one is not available with the localhost hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `bridge` network in both the ES container so that they can discover each other and than use the internal port in order to connect to another container using `curl`.

1. Create a bridge network named as `my-bridge-network`

`docker network create -d bridge my-bridge-network`

2. use above created `my-bridge-network` and custom name in docker run command as

`docker run --network my-bridge  --name es1 -p 9201:9200 -p 9301:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node"  docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.1`

Now, after going inside container one `docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash` run the curl command as `curl es1:9200` which gives proper output.

````
{
  "name" : "vwdvbT9",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "dwMh_zK6RmO_VeeoDQXuTg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.8.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "1fad4e1",
    "build_date" : "2019-06-18T13:16:52.517138Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}```
````

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223139/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-lupidon).